# How to Call a C++ Method in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have C++ files: C.cpp and C.h

```
//C.h
#ifndef __ThreeMoreOpenCV__SourceC__
#define __ThreeMoreOpenCV__SourceC__

#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    static void Cmethod ();
};
#endif

//C.cpp
#include "SourceC.h"

using namespace std;

void Cmethod()
{
    printf("ff");

}
```

Also I have Wrapper.h/.mm

```
//Wrapper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CVWrapper : NSObject
+(void)returnCmethod;
@end

//Wrapper.mm
#import "Wrapper.h"
#import "C.h"

@implementation CVWrapper

+(void)returnCmethod
{
    C::Cmethod();
}

@end
```

I have no idea but i'm getting an error like:

"C::Cmethod()", referenced from:
          +[Wrapper returnCmethod] in Wrapper.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Can anybody tell me what is correct way to call function?

Comment: Edited the title since it was extremely misleading. Also, I would recommend re-naming your 'C' class to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually implemented the Cmethod function in your C class.  You need to implement it with `C::` in the function header, like:

```
void C::Cmethod()
{
    printf("ff");
}
```